# Mi primer MVC en PHP - Funcional, pero lento. ¿Es optimo?, ¿Cómo puedo mejorarlo?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mvc

a continuación os dejo el proyecto de 'MVC' que he realizado por mi cuenta en PHP nativo, y MySQL. Consiste en una 'app' donde escribo notas para recordar cosas, sin login. Muy básico. Escribes una nota, la guarda en la BBDD y el index muestra todas ellas por orden.

Cabe destacar que es mi primer código 'no spagueti', y lo he realizado siguiendo varios vídeos y tutoriales que hay por ahí.
De ahí mi numero de dudas, las cuales presentaré aquí junto con el código, que por cierto, quien quiera mejorarlo, copiarlo, etc. es más que bienvenido. Pero aviso de que es precario.

Expongo primero **mis dudas**, y a continuación os dejaré el proyecto completo:

- En cada lado/ sitio observo que cada uno utiliza un sistema de archivos distintos, Es decir el como y donde guardan los archivos php. El estándar que he visto son las carpetas **controllers**, **views** y **models**, el resto cada uno hace el suyo. **Me gustaría saber si hay algún modelo/patrón que utilicen las empresas, y si el mio es el adecuado.**
- Mi código es funcional (aunque chapucero), y vulnerable a inyecciones SQL, entre otras... Lo he querido hacer lo más 'asequible' posible a una persona (como lo soy yo) primeriza con PHP. Buscando enfocar el funcionamiento, y no el uso malintencionado de este.
  **Pero, es lento, bastante lento de hecho, a destacar la 'página de index' donde muestro todas las notas. El error está en mi código php sin duda, ¿Cómo puedo optimizar esa carga?**
- Generalmente utilizo MySQLi dado que vengo de programación estructurada (creo que se llama), sin POO. Y la he querido seguir usando dado que no es distinta. He leído y conozco las diferencias entre PDO y MySQLi, mi pregunta no es sobre cual usar sin más, mi preguntas es **cual usar teniendo en mente que me preparo académicamente para el mundo laboral en España, y quisiera saber cual es el más usado por las empresas.**
- No llego a comprender bien los controladores-vistas, ¿debe haber una vista por cada método en un controlador, o debe haber tantos controladores como vistas tenga mi aplicación (1x1)?. Dado que por ahí he visto de todo.
- Cualquier mejora y/ o crítica además es más que bienvenida, estoy aprendiendo, y cualquier mínimo detalle, me gustaría poder conocerlo para mejorar.

Contenido del proyecto / Sist. de archivos empleado:

```
config
|_____config.php

controllers
|_____NotaController.php

libs
|_____app.php
|_____Database.php

models
|_____Nota.php

public
|_____css
      |_____styles.css
sql
|_____crearBBDD.sql

views
|_____layout
      |_____footer.php
      |_____header.php
      Nota
      |_____crearNota.php
      |_____editarNota.php
      |_____todas.php

.htaccess
index.php
```

A continuación expongo todos los archivos y su contenido por el orden anterior (de arriba hacia abajo).

Contenido de **config.php**:

```
// constantes globales
define('URL', 'http://localhost/mvcnotes/');
define('DEFAULT_CONTROLLER', 'Nota');
define('DEFAULT_ACTION', 'index');
```

Contenido de **NotaController.php**:

```
<?php
require_once 'models/Nota.php';

class NotaController {

    private $nota;

    public function __construct() {
        //echo 'Nota Controller Creado.';
        $this->nota = new Nota();
    }

    public function index() { // En este caso index va a mostrar todas mis notas
        //echo 'Hola, soy index()';
        $notas = $this->nota->getAll();
        require_once 'views/Nota/todas.php';
    }

    public function crearNota() {
        require_once 'views/Nota/crearNota.php';
    }

    public function guardarNota() {
        $id    = 'null';
        $fecha = 'SYSDATE()';
        if (isset($_POST)) {
            $titulo    = $_POST['titulo'];
            $color     = $_POST['color'];
            $contenido = $_POST['contenido'];

            $this->nota->setId($id);
            $this->nota->setTitulo($titulo);
            $this->nota->setContenido($contenido);
            $this->nota->setColor($color);
            $this->nota->setFecha($fecha);

            if ($this->nota->save($this->nota)) {
                echo 'Nota guardada correctamente';
            } else {
                echo 'No se pudo guardar la nota';
            }
        }
    }

    public function eliminar() {
        if (isset($_GET)) {
            $parametros = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
            $id = $parametros[2];

            if($this->nota->delete($id)) {
                echo 'La nota se eliminó correctamente.';
            } else {
                echo 'La nota no se pudo eliminar';
            }
        }
    }

    public function editar() {
        if (isset($_GET)) {
            $parametros = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
            $id = $parametros[2];

            if($nota = $this->nota->getById($id)) {
                require_once 'views/Nota/editarNota.php';
            }
        }
    }

    public function actualizar() {
        $fecha = 'SYSDATE()';
        if (isset($_POST)) {
            $id        = $_POST['id'];
            $titulo    = $_POST['titulo'];
            $color     = $_POST['color'];
            $contenido = $_POST['contenido'];

            $this->nota->setId($id);
            $this->nota->setTitulo($titulo);
            $this->nota->setContenido($contenido);
            $this->nota->setColor($color);
            $this->nota->setFecha($fecha);

            if ($this->nota->update($this->nota)) {
                echo 'Nota editada correctamente';
            } else {
                echo 'No se pudo editar la nota';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Contenido de **app.php**:

```
<?php
require_once 'config/config.php';

class App {

    public $controller;
    public $controllerObj;
    public $action;

    public function __construct(){

        // Cargo el header para el HTML
        require_once 'views/layout/header.php';

        // Compruebo la URL
        $this->checkURL();
        //echo '<p>El controlador actual es: <b>' . $this->controller . '</b>, y la acción: <b>' . $this->action . '</b></p>';

        // Compruebo el Controlador
        $this->comprobarControlador();

        // Compruebo la accion
        if (!empty($this->action)) {
            $this->comprobarAccion();
        } else {
            $this->action = 'index';
            $this->comprobarAccion();
        }

        // Cargo el footer para el HTML
        require_once 'views/layout/footer.php';
    }

    public function checkURL() {
        // Si recibo parámetros
        if (isset($_GET) && count($_GET) >= 1) {
            // Particiono la URL en parámetros
            $camposURL = explode('/', $_GET['url']);

            // Cuento los parámetros recibidos
            if (count($camposURL) == 3 && $camposURL[0] == 'nota' && is_numeric($camposURL[2])) {
                // Caso especial para editar/elimar nota, que me envian el id por GET como 3er parametro
                $this->controller = $camposURL[0];
                $this->action = $camposURL[1];

            } else if (count($camposURL) == 2) {
                $this->controller = $camposURL[0];
                $this->action = $camposURL[1];

            } else if (count($camposURL) == 1) {
                $this->controller = $camposURL[0];
                $this->action = DEFAULT_ACTION;

            } else {
                echo '<h4 style="color: red;">La url contenía más de 2 parámetros</h4>';
                die();
            }

        // Si no recibo parámetros
        } else {
            $this->controller = DEFAULT_CONTROLLER;
            $this->action = DEFAULT_ACTION;
        }

        // Le añado la terminacion Controller al controlador -> Nota -> NotaController
        $this->controller = $this->controller . 'Controller';
    }

    public function comprobarControlador() {
        // Si el controlador es correcto.
        if (file_exists('controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php')) {
            //echo '<p>El controlador ' . $this->controller . ' existe.</p>';

            // Cargo el controlador
            require_once 'controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';

            // Creo el Objeto controller
            $this->controllerObj = new $this->controller;


        } else {
            echo '<h4 style="color: red;">El controlador ' . $this->controller . ' no se reconoció.</h4>';
            die();
        }
    }

    public function comprobarAccion() {
        // Si la accion existe como método en la clase del controller
        if (method_exists($this->controllerObj, $this->action)) {
            $accion = $this->action;
            // Ejecuto esa accion
            $this->controllerObj->$accion();

        } else {
            echo '<h4 style="color: red;">La accion ' . $this->action . ' no se reconoció.</h4>';
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Contenido de **Database.php**:

```
<?php

class Database {

    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->host = 'localhost';
        $this->user = 'root';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->dbname = 'mvcnotes';
    }

    public function connect() {
        try {
            $conexion = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->dbname);
            $conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            return $conexion;

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error en Database.php -> El erro fue: ' . $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Contenido de **Nota.php**:

```
<?php
require_once 'libs/Database.php';

class Nota {

    private $db;

    private $id;
    private $titulo;
    private $contenido;
    private $color;
    private $fecha;

    public function __construct() {
        $database = new Database();
        $this->db = $database->connect();
    }

    // METODOS PARA BBDD
    public function getAll() {
        $notas = false;
        $resultado = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM notas ORDER BY id DESC");
        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_object('Nota')) {
            $notas[] = $row;
        }

        return $notas;
    }

    public function getById($id) {
        $nota = false;
        $resultado = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM notas WHERE id = $id");
        if ($row = $resultado->fetch_object('Nota')) {
            $nota = $row;
        }
        return $nota;
    }

    public function save($nota) {
        $resultado = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO notas(id, titulo, contenido, color, fecha) VALUES($nota->id, '$nota->titulo', '$nota->contenido', '$nota->color', $nota->fecha)");
        return $resultado;
    }

    public function update($nota) {
        $resultado = $this->db->query("UPDATE notas SET titulo = '$nota->titulo', contenido = '$nota->contenido', color = '$nota->color', fecha = $nota->fecha WHERE id = $nota->id");
        return $resultado;
    }

    public function delete($id) {
        $resultado = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM notas WHERE id = $id");
        return $resultado;
    }

    // GETTERS
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitulo() {
        return $this->titulo;
    }

    public function getContenido() {
        return $this->contenido;
    }

    public function getColor() {
        return $this->color;
    }

    public function getFecha() {
        return $this->fecha;
    }

    // SETTERS
    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setTitulo($titulo) {
        $this->titulo = $titulo;
    }

    public function setContenido($contenido) {
        $this->contenido = $contenido;
    }

    public function setColor($color) {
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    public function setFecha($fecha) {
        $this->fecha = $fecha;
    }

}
```

Contenido de **styles.css**:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body, header, nav, main, section, article, aside, footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
} 

/* CABECERA */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* MENU */
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(lightseagreen, darkslategray);
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav a {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color:darkslategray;
    color: cadetblue;
}

/* PRINCIPAL / MAIN */
main {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center; 
}

main > section {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 150px;
    padding: 20px;
}

main > section span {
    color: darkslategrey;
    font-family: Consolas;
}

main > section a:nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.green {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: goldenrod;
}

.blue {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}

form > p {
    padding: 20px;
}

form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

/* PIE */
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 2px solid darkslategray;
}

footer span {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Contenido de **crearBBDD.sql**:

```
CREATE DATABASE mvcnotes;

USE mvcnotes;

CREATE TABLE notas (
    id          int not null auto_increment,
    titulo      varchar(250) not null,
    contenido   text not null,
    color       varchar(50) not null,
    fecha       datetime not null,
    CONSTRAINT pk_notas PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Contenido de **footer.php**:

```
    </main>

    <!-- FOOTER / PIE -->
    <footer>
        <p>Web, aplicación y modelo MVC creado por <span>Perico los Palotes xD</span> &copy; <?php echo date('Y');?></p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Contenido de **header.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>MVC Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=URL?>public/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HEADER / CABECERA -->
    <header>
        <h1> MVC Notes - Aplicación Web</h1>
    </header>

    <!-- NAV / MENU -->
    <nav>
        <a href="<?=URL?>nota/index">Inicio</a>
        <a href="<?=URL?>nota/crearNota">Crear Nota</a>
    </nav>

    <!-- MAIN / PRINCIPAL -->
    <main>
```

Contenido de **crearNota.php**:

```
<section>
    <h3>Crear Nota</h3>
    <form action="<?=URL?>nota/guardarNota" method="POST">
        <p>
            <label for="titulo">Titulo: </label>
            <input type="text" name="titulo" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="color">Color: </label>
            <select name="color">
                <option value="yellow" selected>Amarillo</option>
                <option value="blue">Azul</option>
                <option value="green">Verde</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="contenido">Contenido: </label>
            <textarea name="contenido" required></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Crear Nota">
            <input type="reset" value="Reiniciar Datos">
        </p>
    </form>
</section>
```

Contenido de **editarNota.php**:

```
<section>
    <h3>Editar Nota</h3>
    <form action="<?=URL?>nota/actualizar" method="POST">
        <p>
            <label for="titulo">Titulo: </label>
            <input type="text" name="titulo" required value="<?= $nota->getTitulo() ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="color">Color: </label>
            <select name="color">
                <option value="yellow" <?php if ($nota->getColor() == 'yellow') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Amarillo</option>
                <option value="blue" <?php if ($nota->getColor() == 'blue') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Azul</option>
                <option value="green" <?php if ($nota->getColor() == 'green') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Verde</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="contenido">Contenido: </label>
            <textarea name="contenido" required><?= $nota->getContenido() ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Editar Nota">
            <input type="reset" value="Reiniciar Datos">
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $nota->getId() ?>">
    </form>
</section>
```

Contenido de **todas.php**:

```
<?php if ($notas) : ?>
    <?php foreach($notas as $nota): ?>
        <section class="seccion <?= $nota->getColor() ?>">
            <article>
                <h3><?= $nota->getTitulo(); ?></h3>
                <span><?= $nota->getFecha() ?></span>
                <p><?= $nota->getContenido(); ?></p>
            </article>
            <div id="botones" class="botones">
                <a href="<?=URL?>nota/editar/<?= $nota->getId() ?>">Editar</a>
                <a href="<?=URL?>nota/eliminar/<?= $nota->getId() ?>">Eliminar</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
        <h3>Wops! No se encontraron notas en la BBDD. Está vacia.</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Contenido de **.htacces**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Contenido de **index.php**:

```
<?php
require_once 'libs/app.php';

$app = new App();
```

**Imagen de la 'web':**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que haría es usar el patrón Singleton es tu clase "database" y ademas cambiarle el nombre a "DatabaseConnection" que es mas descriptivo

Comment: Aunque es una linda pregunta, en cuanto al enfoque, podriamos escribir un libro para contestarte y sin embargo, cada uno tendria un punto de vista diferente. Ni hablar de mirar todo ese codigo. Creo que el mejor consejo es, si funciona, y hace lo que tiene que hacer, esta bien. El resto, lo vas a ganar con experiencia, y leyendo.

Comment: Si sabes inglés puedes intentar hacer tu pregunta en codereview (de la misma red de stackoverflow). En este sitio por lo general se buscan preguntas que no sean tan largas y que se basen más en dudas y problemas bien específicos. Con fe algún día existirá un codereview en español.

Answer (score 2):

Respondiendo a tus preguntas. En la empresa donde trabajo utilizamos esta estructura.

---

```
|-App
|--Controllers
|--Models
|--Midelswares
|--Task
|--Providers

|-Config
|--Database
|--Mailings
|--Sessions
|--Services

|-Database
|--Migrations
|--Querys

|-public

|-resorces
|--js
|--sass
|--views
|--mailingsHTML

|-Route
|--web
|--Api

|-Chanels
|--publics
|--privates

|-test
|--unitTest
|--AppTest

|-vendors
|--Todos los traits que construimos para que funcione
```

Es muy parecida a la que utiliza laravel.

Continuando...

No deberás cargar todos los modelos y controladores porque eso es lo que te esta haciendo sobre carga. Lo que tienes que hacer es aprovecharte de las bondades de php y crearte un kernel que solo se ejecute lo esencial de cada caso de tu framework ejemplo de esto. Es un método que solo cargue un controlador cuando una ruta sea llamada. Y el controlador solo debe de usar el modelo de la tabla cuando la información de esta se valla a utilizar.

```
<?php
namespace Rutadelacarpeta;

class Kernel
{
   public static function($route)
   {
      $rt = explode('@',$route);
      require "App/Controllers/".$rt[0];
      $met = new $rt[0];
      $met->$rt[1];
  }
}
```

Usa static solo en las funciones esenciales que deben de estar precargadas para así sea mucho mas ágil el ejecutar estas funciones. Este ejemplo es muy burdo. Pero en verdad optimiza demasiado el código.

Por otro lado, recuerda que el enfoque de un framework es facilitar el desarrollo de una nueva herramienta. Sin embargo en ningún momento debe de ser restrictivo.

Para explicarte como funciona lo que nuestro equipo ha desarrollado por mas de 1 año tendría que darte una capacitación sobre nuestro framework pero ya no estaría contestando tu pregunta.

La verdad no leí todo tu código. Pero mi consejo es.

Ten siempre en mente que aun que te intentes adecuar a un arquitectura de software, siempre terminaras rompiéndola porque entre más crece un proyecto, más te vas encontrando con casos que no habías contemplado.

En el caso del Modelo Vista Controlador.

Lo que yo te diría. Crea primero el kernel

Has los métodos bien. Necesitas un archivo que pre cargue como es que se van a interpretar:

- Las ruta
- Como se van a ejecutar los controladores
- Como se van a ejecutar los modelos
- Como se van a ejecutar las vistas

Esta es la parte más complicada. Y es la que debe de quedar bien optimizada.

En cuanto a temas de seguridad. Tiene muchas vulnerabilidades por listarte algunas.

1. XSS
2. CSRF
3. SQLI
4. DDoS

Cuando comiences hacer logins tendrás que cifrar las cookies y para apis te recomiendo el protocolo jwt.

Ahora que ves todos estos temas en conjunto es por lo que se tarda mucho tiempo en desarrollar un framework y esto aun que el equipo de desarrollo tenga a mas de 4 personas con mucha experiencia.

Si lo haces por gusto esta muy bien que lo hagas. Si es otro motivo y quieres abordar algunos de los temas que te puse puedes mejor utilizar alguno de estos frameworks que ya esta echo y probados, aparte de tener una excelente comunidad.

- Laravel.
- Synfoni
- CakePHP

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, muchas gracias por todo!